# Using "if else" (and possibly other) conditionals inside \Sexpr{}

Tags: sweave

Is it possible to use conditionals inside \Sexper{} in Sweave? An example of what I'm trying to do is

```
\Sexpr{if(coef(model1)[3]<0){-1*round(coef(model1)[3],3)}else{round(coef(model1)[3],3)}}
```

More elaborately, I want something like

```
\Sexpr{if(x<0){paste(-1*x, "lower", sep="")}else{paste(x, "higher", sep=""}}
```

When I try the first bit of code I get the following error:

```
Error in parse(text = cmd) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1:if(coef(model1)[3]<0){-1*round(coef(model1)[3],3)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help,

-Mark

Comment: Did you check minimal example? Say, is `\Sexpr{if(1<2){"A"}else{"B"}}` works?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I see you have two accounts; an unregistered one (http://stackoverflow.com/users/652916/mark-clements) and this one.  See this link for how to combine them. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste

Answer (score 4):

Curly brackets are not allowed in `Sexpr` expressions.  Instead do the computation in a hidden code chunk and use the result in an `Sexpr`.

See the Sweave manual: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/doc/Sweave.pdf